# Grails DB-Migration for different environments

Tags: grails, database-migration

I'm having a Grails project with the following setup:

- for `development` / `test` issues a `H2` database is used (dev/test environment)
- for `production` an `Oracle` database is used (by a user that has no administration rights eg. schema update) (prod environment)

Now I want two additional environments used for migrating to the dev and prod environment (with another data source and a different change logs eg: `migration/prod/changelog.groovy` and `migration/dev/changelog.groovy`).

How could I establish such a setup?

Answer (score 4):

Since the location of the migrations is specified in Config.groovy you can have different settings per environment. For example:

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.plugin.databasemigration.changelogLocation = 'grails-app/migrations/dev'
    }
    production {
        grails.plugin.databasemigration.changelogLocation = 'grails-app/migrations/prod'
    }
}
```

Check out the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/guide/configuration.html) for the various configuration options and pick the one that suits your needs.